# Imputing a Continuous P-value Distribution from Discrete P-values

Tags: distributions, p-value, continuous-data, data-imputation, discrete-data

I'm exploring methods to create a continuous-like P-value distribution from discrete P-values. For example, consider the process where a balanced coin is tossed four times per experiment to note the occurrence of heads. This procedure is repeated 1,000,000 times to create a null distribution.

[image]

Then, another 1,000,000 coin tosses are performed, each time calculating the probability of achieving an equal or greater number of heads (a right-tailed test) based on the null distribution. This results in a P-value distribution across 1,000,000 instances at five discrete points.

Below is the discrete P-value distribution as a histogram and a CDF plot:

[image]
[image]

The aim is to transition this distribution towards a more continuous spectrum of P-values. The proposed method is as follows:

1. Start with a P-value lower bound of 0 for the right-tailed test.
2. Progressively increase from 0 to the first discrete P-value (e.g., 0.0625), for which there are ~62,500 instances.
3. Uniformly sample floating-point numbers between 0 and 0.0625 ~62,500 times.
4. Adjust the P-value bounds upwards stepwise, repeating the sampling process until reaching a P-value of 1.0.

This technique is reversed for left-tailed tests, initiating the imputation from a P-value of 1.0.

Below is the continuous-like P-value distribution as a histogram and a CDF plot:

[image]
[image]

Would this approach to imputing a continuous-like P-value distribution from discrete data be considered valid and robust?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? The whole point of the distribution (of *P*-values) being discrete is that you cannot observe an outcome that is between an integer number of heads.

Comment: The goal is to evaluate bias in my statistical test. Assessing bias is challenging with the discrete P-value distribution's CDF plot; however, a continuous-like P-value distribution simplifies bias detection.

Comment: I can't really understand what you are after, but maybe you should search 'continuity correction'.